# Where can I find Theme Editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I searched everywhere. I even used "Search Everywhere" tool and it showed nothing.
[The evidence of disappearing Theme Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXORI.png)
So, guys can you help me with that a little bit?

Comment: Menubar -> Tools -> Theme Editor?

Comment: same here.. I could not find it anymore... it used to be available.

Comment: @LoganRodie [There's nothing about it, or I'm blind](https://imgur.com/KYxF3co). I looked for it everywhere I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Theme Editor for Android studio 3 has been removed for no good reason. See for yourself here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119271605

Answer (score 0):

Just updated my Android Studio and alas, my Theme Editor has disappeared too. Take a look at [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119271605), apparently its been disabled and is now obsolete.